# Removing headers from blog post "excerpts" (using Hacksaw)

Tags: plugin-hacksaw

I'm using hacksaw to display the first part of my article on a blog listing page.

```
{{ entry.body|hacksaw(chars='300',allow='<p>', append='...') }}
```

The issue I have is when an article starts with a heading in it's body it looks like the attached. I'd ideally like to remove any headings from the excerpts.

[image]

[image]

As you can see the headings 'Reducing the size...' and 'Scaling' come through as plain text and the rest continues with my allowed

The only way I can think to do this is to allow their headings (h2 and h3) and then hide them in CSS, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Twig [replace](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#replace) filter with a regular expression, this'll remove the tag and it's content.

```
{{ entry.body | replace('/<h([1-6])>.*?<\\/h([1-6])>/', '') | raw | hacksaw(chars='300',allow='<p>', append='...') }}
```

The only limitation is regular expressions aren't fantastic with nested html tags, so your mileage my vary!

You might need to play around with the Regex a bit if you want to just limit it to a few headings, this will strip all h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6. You also might not need the `| raw` filter, it seemed to escape everything after the replace when I quickly tested it.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider replacing all of your heading tags manually with the [replace](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#replace) twig filter.

This would replace all headings with a paragraph:
`{{ entry.body|replace({'h1': 'p', 'h2': 'p', 'h3': 'p', 'h4': 'p', 'h5': 'p', 'h6': 'p'})|hacksaw(chars='300', allow='<p>', append='...') }}`

Comment: Thanks. I actually want to remove the headings rather than have them display as paragraph text. Having the heading text as part of the body doesn't really work

Comment: You could like to remove the contents of whatever is in the heading tags?

Comment: Yes, remove the content with heading tags rather than just the tags.

Comment: One lazy way of doing that is allowing headings and after that via the power of CSS `display:none` it.

Comment: Yes that was my initial thought but agree it's a bit lazy so thought I'd see if there was a better option.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a plugin called [Retcon](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) which uses [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to re-write HTML content. There's a couple of ways you could achieve your goal easily using Retcon:

Remove all header tags (and their content), using the [`retconRemove`](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Remove) filter:

```
{{ entry.body|retconRemove(['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6']) }}
```

Remove everything except paragraphs, using the [`retconOnly`](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Only) filter:

```
{{ entry.body|retconOnly('p') }}
```

Remove everything except paragraphs and images:

```
{{ entry.body|retconOnly(['p', 'img']) }}
```

As for truncating the content, I'd probably add the hacksaw filter after using Retcon, i.e.

```
{{ entry.body|retconOnly('p')|hacksaw(chars='300',allow='<p>', append='...') }}
```